# Can the solution be improved?

Tags: java, algorithm

**PROBLEM STATEMENT**

> It is the wedding day of Sanchi, the beautiful princess of Byteland.
>   Her fiance Krishna is planning to gift her an awesome ruby necklace.
>   Krishna has currently b -blue rubies, g -green rubies, r-red rubies
>   and y -yellow rubies. He has to arrange the rubies next to each other
>   in a straight line to make the necklace. But, there are a couple of
>   rules to be followed while making this necklace:
>
> - A blue ruby should be followed by either a blue ruby or a red ruby
> - A green ruby should be followed by either a green ruby or a yellow ruby
> - A red ruby should be followed by either a green ruby or a yellow ruby
> - A yellow ruby should be followed by either a blue ruby or a red ruby
> - If it is possible, we should always start a necklace with a blue or a red ruby
>
> Can you tell what is the maximum possible length of the necklace that
>   Krishna can make. The length of a necklace is the number of rubies in
>   it.
>
> Input Format
>
> - The first line contains an integer representing b.
> - The second line contains an integer representing r.
> - The third line contains an integer representing y.
> - The fourth line contains an integer representing g.
>
> Constraints
>
> - 0 <= b, r, y, g <= 2000
> - At least one of b, r, y, g is greater than 0
>
> Output Format
>
> - A single integer which is the answer to the problem.
>
> Sample TestCase 1
>
> ```
> Input
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 0
> Output
> 3
> ```

**My Solution :**

```
package ruby;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CandidateCode {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(System.in));
        Integer b = new Integer(br.readLine());
        Integer r = new Integer(br.readLine());
        Integer y = new Integer(br.readLine());
        Integer g = new Integer(br.readLine());

        if (b + r + y + g > 0 && b <= 2000 && b <= 2000 && r <= 2000 && 
g <= 2000 && y <= 2000 && b >= 0 && r >= 0
                && g >= 0 && y >= 0) {

            ArrayList<Character> necklace = new ArrayList<Character>();
            CandidateCode rn = new CandidateCode();
            int length = rn.calculateLengthofNecklace(b, r, y, g, 
necklace);
            System.out.println(length);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

}

private int calculateLengthofNecklace(Integer b, Integer r, Integer y, Integer g, ArrayList<Character> necklace) {
    if (anyRemaining(b))
        necklace = addBlue(b, r, y, g, necklace);
    else if (anyRemaining(r))
        necklace = addRed(b, r, y, g, necklace);
    else if (anyRemaining(g))
        necklace = addGreen(b, r, y, g, necklace);
    else if (anyRemaining(y))
        necklace = addYellow(b, r, y, g, necklace);
    // System.out.println("necklace :" + necklace.toString());
    return necklace.size();
}

private ArrayList<Character> addRed(Integer b, Integer r, Integer y, Integer g, ArrayList<Character> necklace) {
    char lastruby = necklace.size() > 0 && necklace.get(necklace.size() - 1) != null
            ? necklace.get(necklace.size() - 1) : 'z';
    if (anyRemaining(r) && (lastruby == 'y' || lastruby == 'b' || lastruby == 'z')) {
        necklace.add('r');
        r = r - 1;
        // System.out.println("in addRed\n b:" + b + " r: " + r + " y: " + y
        // + " g: " + g);
    } else {
        return necklace;
    }
    ArrayList<Character> n1 = new ArrayList<Character>(necklace);
    ArrayList<Character> n2 = new ArrayList<Character>(necklace);
    n1 = addGreen(b, r, y, g, n1);
    n2 = addYellow(b, r, y, g, n2);
    necklace = n1.size() > n2.size() ? n1 : n2;
    return necklace;

}

private ArrayList<Character> addYellow(Integer b, Integer r, Integer y, Integer g, ArrayList<Character> necklace) {
    char lastruby = necklace.size() > 0 && necklace.get(necklace.size() - 1) != null
            ? necklace.get(necklace.size() - 1) : 'z';
    if (anyRemaining(y) && (lastruby == 'r' || lastruby == 'g' || lastruby == 'z')) {
        necklace.add('y');
        y = y - 1;
        // System.out.println("in addYellow\n b:" + b + " r: " + r + " y: "
        // + y + " g: " + g);
    } else {
        return necklace;
    }
    ArrayList<Character> n1 = new ArrayList<Character>(necklace);
    ArrayList<Character> n2 = new ArrayList<Character>(necklace);
    n1 = addBlue(b, r, y, g, n1);
    n2 = addRed(b, r, y, g, n2);
    necklace = n1.size() > n2.size() ? n1 : n2;
    return necklace;
}

private ArrayList<Character> addGreen(Integer b, Integer r, Integer y, Integer g, ArrayList<Character> necklace) {
    char lastruby = necklace.size() > 0 && necklace.get(necklace.size() - 1) != null
            ? necklace.get(necklace.size() - 1) : 'z';
    if (anyRemaining(g) && (lastruby == 'r' || lastruby == 'g' || lastruby == 'z')) {
        necklace.add('g');
        g = g - 1;
        // System.out.println("in addGreen\n b:" + b + " r: " + r + " y: " +
        // y + " g: " + g);
    } else {
        return necklace;
    }
    ArrayList<Character> n1 = new ArrayList<Character>(necklace);
    ArrayList<Character> n2 = new ArrayList<Character>(necklace);
    n1 = addGreen(b, r, y, g, n1);
    n2 = addYellow(b, r, y, g, n2);
    necklace = n1.size() > n2.size() ? n1 : n2;
    return necklace;

}

private ArrayList<Character> addBlue(Integer b, Integer r, Integer y, Integer g, ArrayList<Character> necklace) {
    char lastruby = necklace.size() > 0 && necklace.get(necklace.size() - 1) != null
            ? necklace.get(necklace.size() - 1) : 'z';
    if (anyRemaining(b) && (lastruby == 'y' || lastruby == 'b' || lastruby == 'z')) {
        necklace.add('b');
        b = b - 1;
        // System.out.println("in addBlue\n b:" + b + " r: " + r + " y: " +
        // y + " g: " + g);
    } else {
        return necklace;
    }
    ArrayList<Character> n1 = new ArrayList<Character>(necklace);
    ArrayList<Character> n2 = new ArrayList<Character>(necklace);
    n1 = addBlue(b, r, y, g, n1);
    n2 = addRed(b, r, y, g, n2);
    necklace = n1.size() > n2.size() ? n1 : n2;
    return necklace;

}

private boolean anyRemaining(Integer b) {
    return b > 0;

}

}
```

**Can this solution be made better?**

Comment: This question would probably work better on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com), our sister site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs to [codereview.se]

Comment: What do you mean by better? faster? more memory efficient? clearer? more testable? more maintainable? better documented?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there is a neater solution than this. If you had 2000 of each of the beads (or even 2000 in total), this would take a horrifically long time to fine a solution.

Comment: For example: `(all B)+R+(all G)+Y+R+Y+R...` would be the longest under some circumstances.

Comment: Could you tell me if this question is from a online judge.Just to check my solution

Comment: @thebenman : this question was a part of a recently conducted challenge on techgig

Comment: @RichaBasak Could you give me the link if it's still open?

Comment: @thebenman the contest is closed now.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: you can calculate it simply as `b + g + max(2 * min(r, y), 1 + 2 * min(r - 1, y))`

The problem with your implementation is that it branches like crazy: if you have a large number of beads, it will take each of the choices - lots of choices - and so it will take a really long time to finish.

I think that the actual construction of longest necklaces is actually pretty simple (even if it results in dull necklaces). I've implemented this [here](https://ideone.com/zGEiLz), if you want to try it out.

You can construct a graph of all the possible transitions:

```
digraph G {
  "B" -> "B"
  "B" -> "R"
  "G" -> "G"
  "R" -> "G"
  "R" -> "Y"
  "G" -> "Y"
  "Y" -> "B"
  "Y" -> "R"
}
```

You can only visit each of these nodes a certain number of times: you can visit the `B` node `b` times, `G` node `g` times etc.

If you have at least one of each bead, you have to start at B or R. So,the longest necklace is given by:

```
(all B)+R+(all G)+Y+R+Y+R+...
  or
R+(all G)+Y+R+Y+R+...+(all B))
```

where `...` means to repeat the Y/R alternation until you run out of beads.

So the length is `max(b + 2*min(r, y) + g, 1 + g + min(r-1, y) + b)`.

Similarly, you can think about the best path if some of the numbers are zero.

If you have zero of one kind:

- If `b=0`, start at R: the maximum length is `2*min(r, y + 1) + g`
- If `r=0`, start at B: the maximum length is `b`
- If `g=0`, start at B: the maximum length is `b + 2*min(r,y)`
- If `y=0`, start at B: the maximum length is `v + 1 + g`

If you have zero of two kinds:

- If `b=r=0`, start at G: the maximum length is `g + 1`
- If `b=g=0`, start at R: the maximum length is `2*min(r, y + 1)`
- If `b=y=0`, start at R: the maximum length is `1 + g`
- If `r=g=0`, start at B: the maximum length is `b`
- If `r=y=0`, start at B: the maximum length is `b`
- If `g=y=0`, start at B: the maximum length is `b + 1`

If you have zero of three kinds (or, rather, only one kind is non-zero):

- If `b != 0`, start at B: the maximum length is `b`
- If `r != 0`, start at R: the maximum length is `1`
- If `g != 0`, start at G: the maximum length is `g`
- If `y != 0`, start at Y: the maximum length is `1`.

You never have zero of all 4 kinds, so there is no case to consider there.

So, a far more efficient solution would be simply to check each of these cases.

However, if you compare all of the logic here, you can find that there is a simple expression which covers all the cases:

```
b + g + max(2 * min(r, y), 1 + 2 * min(r - 1, y));
```

So, just implement that! This runs effectively instantly, unlike the original code.

This tells you the *length* of the longest necklace; but it wouldn't be hard to construct a necklace satisfying the length.

Comment: Not sure the simplified expression works if r=y=0?

Comment: @Peter I guess you are right: that would be `b`, I suppose.

Comment: For case `b=g=0`, the simplified expression is incorrect for case result in odd number(e.g. 2r1y). Case `b=0` and `g=0` have same problem. Case `y=0` has a typo.